# update choosen items price using rxAndroid

Tags: android, rx-android

I am practicing using `RxAndroid`design pattern in my projects.
I have list of objects which are items info for sale.
I show them in `RecyclerView`which user can select one or more of them and increase the number of each item. or can deselect the item and remove it from his/her basket.
I have `TextView`too, that sum the price of all items chosen (calculate the count of each item too).
the value of this `TextView` is real time, it means when user select/deselect any item or decrease/increase count of each item the sum price changes so the `TextView` value changes too.

I want to use RxAndroid for handling this. I know bases of RxJava, RxAndroid, I use this getting data from server with `Retrofit`.

I think the sum price variable is Observable, and I should call onNext() method of it any time changes happen.

I need some help maybe some part of code examples which give me idea how to code this.
thanks

Comment: rxAndroid is just a small library that adds some Android-specific feature to RxJava. RxJava is what you need. You need to study RxJava. You can find many tutorials about RxJava. Just google it

Comment: my problem is not RxAndroid or RxJava, it's all about Rx. I want to code the thing I described above , but I am not sure how.

Comment: RxJava is complex. If you want to use it you need to study it properly. It can't be explained in an answer on StackOverflow. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0IKHxjkgop4

Comment: thanks for link, I know base structures of RxJava, but in coding thing like I mentioned I have problem. I don't know how to connect what I want to RxJava.

Comment: BTW you cannot call the onNext of an observable. You can call it on an Emitter that you get for example as a param of subscribe in the ObservableOnSubscribe. Or you need to use a Subject

Comment: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp-rxjava/